# Comando correcto

Tags: x86

Hola amigos de Stackoverflow, tengo una pregunta tonta sobre **Assembler**, quisiera saber si este comando esta correcto, y si no lo esta porque no es correcto?

```
Mov Al,Ah
```

muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mov Al,Ah

**Trata de colocar las instrucciones de assembler en mayúsculas todas las letras o sino todas en minúsculas.**

Si tienes una variable **AX**. **AL** viene siendo la parte "baja" de **AX** conformado por 8 bits o un "byte" y **AH** viene siendo la parte "alta" de **AX** conformado igualmente por 8 bits o un "byte".

**AL** también es referenciada como la parte menos significativa de **AX** mientras que **AH** también es referenciada como la parte más significativa de **AX**.

Concretamente `MOV AL,AH` es una instrucción perfectamente válida la cual se lee como: Copia la parte alta (AH) del registro de 16 bits **AX** a la parte más baja (AL) o lo que es lo mismo sobreescribe el valor de la parte menos significativa (AL) de **AX** con el valor de la parte mas significativa (AH). Al ser ambos registros de 8 bits cada uno no existe ningún problema en mover los bits de uno a otro.

Comment: @NaCl es así. Ya cambio la frase. Muchas gracias por la observación!

Comment: Como adición, mencionaría las variantes de sintaxis ASM, actualmente la instrucción tratada está con la sintaxis de intel, el equivalente en AT&T sería `movb %ah %al`, pero eso realmente no tiene mucho que ver, sólo un comentario :), muy buena respuesta!

Comment: @NaCl Gracias nuevamente. Es así la sintaxis tiene que ver con los intel como el 8086 por ejemplo!